# Calculating the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0-} (1/x)\cdot e^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

To approach this problem, I was thinking of doing l'hopital rule, but I don't think it works?

you have $\dfrac{e^{1/x}}x$. When you take derivative you're going to get

$$\dfrac{-x^{-2}e^{1/x}}1 = \dfrac{-e^{1/x}}{x^2}.$$

If i keep taking l'hopital rule of this problem, I will keep getting an $x^2$.

Is there another way? I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, I just can't see it.

Comment: $t=1/x$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$

Comment: I know, I keep getting an indeterminate form

Comment: $te^t$ doesn't give an indeterminate form when $t\to +\infty$. The other one is well known too.

Comment: e^1/x is going to 0, so wouldn't you have 0/0?

Comment: When $x \rightarrow 0$, the fraction $1/x$ is approaching infinity, not zero. That means $e^{1/x}$ is approaching infinity, as well.

Comment: Austin Mohr: The title has been modified : $x\to 0^-$

Comment: lim x-0- of e^(1/x) = 0; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0-+e%5E%281%2Fx%29

Comment: That's equivalent to $\lim_{t\to +\infty} -te^{-t}$.

Answer (score 4):

If you make the change of variable $x\to z^{-1}$, as $x\to 0^-,z\to-\infty$ and in this case your limit turns into $\lim_{z\to-\infty}ze^z=\lim_{z\to-\infty}\dfrac{z}{e^{-z}}=0$ :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=-\frac{1}{x}$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{-t}{e^t}=0$$

Comment: How come you can change the the limit from 0- to infinity?

Comment: @BillyThompson: Because if $x$ approaches $0$ from the left, then $t=-\frac{1}{x}$ approaches infinity.